# How to launch the Qt Application from .Desktop file for linux in chromebook?

Tags: linux, qt, chromebook

I am facing the issue in launching the Qt application for linux from .desktop file in chromebook. can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Below I mentioned The linux version I am using:

```
**PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"**
```

I created the .desktop file like this.Can any one correct me if I wrong in creation of .desktop file

```
**[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Name=XYZ
Comment=trayIconCreation
Exec= Executable with full path
Icon=Icon with full path
Type=Application**
```

Below I mentioned the issue I am facing:

When I click on the desktop icon to launch the application it doesn't work for me.But if i try to launch the application through terminal its working fine.Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue

Comment: Maybe this application does not support launch from an arbitrary path? In this case you'll have to create a bash script that will launch it from the app path and write path to this script file inside of your .desktop file.

Comment: Hello Alexander,
I tried out your solution,but I could not able to launch the application from desktop icon. Is there any other way to launch the application through desktop icon